# Why is my custom-defined Google Analytics event not firing?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm building a landing page template for a client in WordPress. The page's primary conversion action is a lead-gen form that's contained within a Bootsrap 4 modal window. I have the form submission triggering a custom GA event - no problem there, but **I am having trouble triggering an event for when the modal window is launched.**

I have the global (UA) site tag hard-coded into the  of the landing page (I omitted the UA ID for this example, but that is entered correctly on the page)

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics: UA-XXXXXXX-X -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12360587-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
    </script>
```

In a separate JS file, which is being enqueued in the footer of the site, I am hooking into the built-in *shown* method for the Boostrap modal window:

```
$('#modalsem').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Form - Breadcrumb', 'Open', 'SEM');
        });
```

I have verified that the `shown` method *is* firing (I've tested with simple login to the console), but for some reason the custom `ga()` event I defined isn't sending any data to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you using google tag manager and trying to do event push using old method which not working with GTM. 
If you can;t include old style google analytics code, you should change how you push events. 
Try reading https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/what-is-data-layer-in-google-tag-manager

Comment: that is odd that the script is saying tag manager like that, but I just logged into the clients Analytics account and went to the tracking code section and that's exactly how it's appearing directly in the Analytics admin.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ga with gtag and it should work:

```
gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category' : 'Mobile', 'event_action' : 'Original', 'event_label' : 'App'});"
```